# Amount of flatMap executions depends on observer pull, while single is needed

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java, rxjs

I have a push notification mechanism (PublishSubject) which triggers http request logic (flatMap). Basic scenario is that whenever a push arrives,  single http call is made and results propagated to multiple observers.

I've written a simple demo for the case but flatMap executes for each registered observer, while I would like it to be triggered just once on each push.

```
PublishSubject<Integer> subject = PublishSubject.create();
Observable<String> obs = subject.asObservable().flatMap(integer -> {
    // this code runs for each observer, which is twice in this case
    return Observable.just(String.valueOf(integer));
});


Observer mock = mock(Observer.class);
Observer mock1 = mock(Observer.class);
obs.subscribe(mock);
obs.subscribe(mock1);

subject.onNext(1);
```

Could you suggest a fix?

Thanks

P.S. Right now I'm using cache(1) to fix the issue but I'm not sure if it's ok to do it this way. Moreover, I can't just quite understand why a single stream of execution would depend on amount of observers attached. Can you comment on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already sort of using it, you need either `publish()` + `connect()` or `publish().refCount()` if you want to make the value shareable by multiple observables. The first case lets you control when to actually make the `Observable` go hot, while the second will go live as soon as you subscribe the first time. RxJS also has `share` which wraps `publish().refCount()` not sure if RxJava has that as well.

```
PublishSubject<Integer> subject = PublishSubject.create();
Observable<String> obs = subject.asObservable().flatMap(integer -> {
    // this code runs for each observer, which is twice in this case
    return Observable.just(String.valueOf(integer));
}).publish().refCount();


Observer mock = mock(Observer.class);
Observer mock1 = mock(Observer.class);
obs.subscribe(mock);
obs.subscribe(mock1);

subject.onNext(1);
```

Comment: Yep, RxJava has .share() as well